# How to edit a page layout

Tags: page-layout, aspx

I need to edit a page layout to include new fields.  I have looked at the ASPX file and seen the current fields.

This for example

```
</PageFieldDateTimeField:DateTimeField>
<PageFieldRichHtmlField:RichHtmlField FieldName="66f500e9-7955-49ab-abb1-663621727d10" runat="server">
```

I do not know the fieldnames of the fields that I wish to insert? How can I find these names out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the page layout in SharePoint designer and then [add](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint-designer-help/customize-a-publishing-page-layout-HA010174129.aspx) the available fields using the Toolbox

[image]